# How should I structure inheritance for PouchDB persistence?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, mixins, pouchdb

I'm writing a collection of related objects in JS that I want to store in PouchDB but the default prototype inheritance behavior does not groove with persistence layers. How can I have a structure that can inherit some properties from a parent as enumerable OwnProperties but other properties (functions) like a prototype? I'll need to make some properties writable/configurable and some frozen, and I'll have 10e5-10e6 objects so keeping memory footprint and performance in mind is critical.

PouchDB will accept any JS object and scrape its enumerable properties, skipping prototype properties. This makes perfect sense and PouchDB is awesome. 
My objects are a family that share some properties and methods with each generation adding a few more of each and keeping all the parent's as well.

I'll use the Shapes trope for simplicity.

```
Shape.properties={
  x:0,                                        // Vanilla x displacement
  y:0,                                        // Vanilla y displacement 
  color:red,                                  // We want this to be immutable
};
Shape.methods={
  move:function(x,y){this.x+=x; this.y+=y;},  // Change displacement
  reset:function(){this.x=0; this.y=0;},      // Back to origin
  save:function(){db.put(this);},             // Persist to DB
}

Rectangle.properties={
  w:2,                                        // Width
  h:1,                                        // Height
};
Rectangle.methods={
  aspect:function(w,h){this.w=(w/h)*this.h;}, // Stretch 
};

Cube.properties={
  z:0,                                        // Elevation
};

Cube.methods={
  lift:function(z){this.z+=z;};               // Float up
};
```

If i use normal JS prototype inheritance and make a Cube it will only have OwnProperties of z, which makes persistence useless.
So I made a helper module to fix this, it has functions that I can use to make quick PropertyDescriptors using a bitmask and a combine function to cobble all the parts together:

```
    // writable=4 | enumerable=2 | configurable=1
    /* Process a bitMask that describes the desired property descriptor. We then use the combine method to add 
     * specifically described properties to an object. PouchDB will grab any enumerable properties, some should be write-protected 
     * but vanilla properties are Accessors with bitmask 6(enumerable and writable). Based on code from elsewhere. */

    accessor:function(bMask,val){ // Accessor descriptor: bitmask , value
        return {configurable:Boolean(bMask & 1),enumerable:Boolean(bMask & 2),writable:Boolean(bMask & 4),value:val};
        },

    combine:function(root,properties,methods){                       // This is a naive implementation, ask SO for help? 

        for (let i in root){                                         // Iterate over properties.
           properties[i]=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(root,i);    // Combine the root properties and the given properties objects, 
        }                              
        methods=Object.defineProperties(Object.getPrototypeOf(root),methods);// Add the methods to the root prototype.               
        return Object.create(methods,properties);                    // Combine the prototype and the properties
    },
```

My structures now look something like

```
Shape.properties={
  x:accessor(6,0),
  y:accessor(6,0),
  color:accesor(2,red),                                   // Bitmask 2: enumerable only
};
Shape.methods={
  move:accessor(0,function(x,y){this.x+=x; this.y+=y;}),   // Bitmask 0: 'Frozen' property
  reset:accessor(0,function(){this.x=0; this.y=0;}),
  save:accessor(0,function(){db.put(this);}),
}
var Shape=function(){
  return combine(new Object(),Shape.properties, Shape.methods);
};


Rectangle.properties={
  w:accessor(6,0),
  h:accessor(6,0),
};
Rectangle.methods={
  aspect:accessor(0,function(w,h){this.w=(w/h)*this.h;}),
};

var Rectangle=function(){
  return combine(new Shape(),Rectangle.properties, Rectangle.methods);
};

//...
```

So this works, BUT two objects of the same type no longer share a prototype, that is to say each object has a unique prototype instance.

This is crap for memory, and bad practice in general. I may as well write the methods to each object and let pouch spit them back out at me as errors.

I looked into other options and ran across [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-subclassing/) which has some great leads but then I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation) that makes me think that maybe I should be creating static/frozen prototype objects and building from there or taking a different approach entirely.

I've also looked at using Object.assign() but it can heavily modify the properties being copied.

It's likely that there is a simple solution that I am not seeing, do you know what it is? or can you help me find it?

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around and experimenting some more I found that a frozen prototype seems to work, assuming that doesn't trigger the optimization errors referenced above. The structure I have now is like

```
const methods={},properties={};

properties.Shape=Object.freeze({
    x:{value: 0, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
    y:{value: 0, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}, 
    color:{value: 'red', writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false},   
});

methods.Shape=Object.freeze({
        move:{value:function(x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        console.info('Shape moved.');
        return this;},writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
});

const Shape=function() {return Object.defineProperties(this,properties.Shape);}
Shape.prototype=Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties({},methods.Shape));



properties.Rectangle=Object.freeze({
    w:{value: 0, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
    h:{value: 0, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
  });

  methods.Rectangle=Object.freeze({
    zoom:{value:function(z){
    this.w=this.w*z;
    this.h=this.h*z;
    console.info('Rectangle zoomed');
    return this;},writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
});

const Rectangle=function() {    Shape.call(this); return Object.defineProperties(this,properties.Rectangle);};
Rectangle.prototype = Object.freeze(Object.create(Shape.prototype,methods.Rectangle));

var rect = new Rectangle();

  console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?',
    rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
  console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?',
    rect instanceof Shape); // true
  rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
  rect.zoom(2); // {x:1,y:1,w:0,h:0}
  rect2=new Rectangle();
  console.log('Do rect2 and rect share a prototype?',
  rect2.prototype===rect.prototype); // yes
  shape=new Shape();
  shape.move(2,2);  // moves
  shape.zoom(2);    // Fails as expected
```

Cleaning it up with the helper function should make it prettier and easier to update.